# Json like string parsing in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Please help me to parse a JSON like string in Android. The string is as follows:

```
{stnCode:"station1",arrTime:"22:08",depTime:"22:10",distance:14}
```

Please note the the key is not enclosed in `""` , so it cannot be treated as a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use gson libarary
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Create an object and do new Gson().parseJson()
It's the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Step 1** - Get the main string and split it by `,`. As a result you will get an array of string which has key and value. Use `yourString.split()`method.

**Step 2** - Use `for loop` to iterate all the strings in the array. Get each string and split/parse it by ':'. Now you will get key and value as a separate string.

**Step 3** - If value has "" then consider it as a `String` otherwise it is `Integer`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: eventhough i mentioned only a single line,my actual data contains lot of key value pairs . example is   https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq3sexzdxkcmi0v/response.txt